# format rss feed pubDate

Tags: javascript

I am trying to format the dates of an rss feed to month/day/year (8/3/2012).  I am doing that with the following code:

```
// pubDate
postDate = new Date("Fri Aug 03 2012 06:08:11 GMT-0700");
// reformat pubDate
pubDate = postDate.getMonth() + "/" + postDate.getDate() + "/" + postDate.getFullYear();
// return pubDate
console.log(pubDate + " pubDate");
```

With my current code the output is 7/3/2012 but the month is not correct. I get 7 and not 8. How do I make it produce the correct month?

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/LmZMX/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[getMonth()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp) returns "A Number, from 0 to 11, representing the month"

```
(postDate.getMonth() + 1)
```